# Java Using Robot to Output letters (Capitalized and uncapitalized)

Tags: java, methods, awtrobot

I am using this method to try and type out my letters into a form. Though when the char gets converted back to chars, they are not capitalized. What would be the most efficient way to capitalize specific letters?

My Attempt:

```
private static void type(String s) throws AWTException
{
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    for (byte b : bytes)
    {
        int code = b;
        try
        {
            if (code > 96 && code < 123)
            code = code - 32;
            bot.delay(40);
            bot.keyPress(code);
            bot.keyRelease(code);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not read code: " + code + ". Report this to MrGermanrain!");
        }
    }
}
```

This did not work because it only wrote lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
bot.delay(40);
bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
bot.keyPress(code);
bot.keyRelease(code);
bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
//rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! Very simple solution. I'll go get this a shot.